# Query Creation Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a bunch of Car Objects.  I'm able to render a list of all the Car Objects with each field being displayed on `list.html`.  If I just wanted to display a list of `make` values on `list.html`, how would I go about that by using a query?  Looking in Spring Data JPA Docs section 5.3.2, could I do something like `findByAllMake();`?

I've tried `findByAllMake();`...

The below code shows how I am successfully getting a complete list of all the objects.  Looking to just get a list of all `make`s.

Car.java

```
package com.example.demo;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String year;


    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String id, String make, String model, String year) {
        this.id = id;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

CarController.java :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;


@Controller
public class CarController {



    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;


    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String carMakeList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("list", carRepository.getAllMakes());

        return "list";
    }


}
```

CarRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM car;", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Car> getAllMakes();


}
```

I've tried `findByAllMake();` but I get back an Unsatisfactory Dependency error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'carController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'carService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CarRepository.findAllByMake()! No parameter available for part make SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals] NEVER.
```

Comment: What is the type of a "make"? Is it `Car`? I doubt it. So your query shouldn't return a List<Car>. It should also not use SQL, but JPQL. How is a make related to a Car? That is important to know in order to write the correct query? Post the code of the Car entity.

Comment: Just posted the Car entity.  `make` is a `String`. Thanks.

Comment: Not...sure why you're trying to create a native query here.  You can get by without the native query and just use `findAll`; there's some Spring syntactic sugar you're running into in which the process which generates your method is seeing "By" and is freaking out because you're not providing a parameter to the method.

Comment: Why is `car.make` a string? Isn't it a car brand? If so, why not have it as an entity as well?

Answer (score 0):

Makes are Strings. So if you want your method to return a list of makes, its return type should be `List<String>`, not `List<Car>`.

And the query needs to select makes, not cars:

```
select distinct car.make from Car car
```

Comment: Thanks.. tried this and got a thymeleaf error.  I'm trying to learn about querying in Spring Data JPA however not sure where to begin as there are so many ways to query it seems.  Looking for a guide, example, tutorial or something as the Spring Docs are either not helpful to me or above my head at the moment.

Comment: A thymeleaf error has nothing to do with a JPA query. What you need to do is to *read* the error message and stack trace and reason about it. Not find a tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't run this on my laptop but what if you try:
to add constructor to CarController:

```
public CarController(CarRepository carRepository){
this.carRepository = carRepository;
}
```

And then probably just try:

```
public List<Car> findAll();
```

in the repository?